# Reference to this inside prototype function

Tags: javascript, this

I am struggling hard with the `this` keyword in javascript. I have read lot of articles and answers but I don't understand how to apply all this knowledge to my simple piece of code.

Here is my "mediator" object:

```
function Mediator() {
        this.registered = {}
    }

    Mediator.prototype = {
        constructor: Mediator,

    register: function (id, e) {
        this.registered[id] = e;
        e.m = this; //<-- here 
    },

    broadcast: function() {...}
}
```

but when on in a registered object I try to do

```
this.m.broadcast("Connected");
```

I got the wonderful `Uncaught TypeError: cannot call method broadcast on undefined`.

Edit:

I want the `e` object to keep a reference on the mediator so I can use the broadcast method later on inside `e`. My problem is that `e` doesn't keep the reference that I set inside the register method.

Edit2:

It seems that returning an anonymous object instead of using prototype does the job:

```
function Mediator() {
    var registered = {}

    return {
        register: function (id, e) {
                      this.registered[id] = e;
                      e.m = this; //<-- here 
                  },

        broadcast: function() {...}
    }
}
```

This way, setting m to this works fine and I can later call broadcast inside my other objects. Maybe this is not the pure right answer, but as long as I don't find a better one...

Comment: thats because you define this.broadcast, not this.m.broadcast...

Comment: I call broadcast in an object that I have registered in mediator. All my objects have the "m" field, which I am  trying to point to the mediator. Sorry if my description is unclear.

Comment: http://ideone.com/u6VMez - please explain what's the problem

Comment: This works fine for me : http://jsfiddle.net/UVcz3/

Comment: yeah, I just tested it and it works when everything is in the same page. It doesn't work when I put object declaration in a separate js file and include it.

Comment: The `this` pointer can refer to many things depending upon the context. Since you're calling `this.m.broadcast("Connected")` I believe your problem is that the `this` pointer itself doesn't point to a registered object. For example, consider: `var m = new Mediator; var o = {}; m.register("o", o);`. Now I can use `o.m.broadcast("Connected");` but I can't use `this.m.broadcast("Connected");` because in this case `this` points to the global object - in the case of the browser that's `window`. If you're using it inside `Mediator` itself then just use `this.broadcast` instead of `this.m.broadcast`.

Comment: Ok, pretty clear thx !

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.e= m;` or `this.m = e;` not sure what you want to do with this. 
Method is called like this: `broadcast("Connected)` you don't need to specify this. or m. when you are calling it. Hope this helps a bit.